# Android SDK Command line tools doesn't install cleanly in Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I was following along with a new React Native course on my Windows 11 PC when I was surprised when I noticed that it didn't appear that the Android Studio SDK Command line tools didn't appear to be installed in Android Studio:

[image: Android SDK Settings]

I tried installing them and I get the following message:

```
Packages to install: - Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) (cmdline-tools;latest)


Preparing "Install Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) (revision: 9.0)".
Package "com.android.repository.impl.generated.v2.RemotePackage@f2c9fb88" (cmdline-tools;latest) should be installed in 
"C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest" but 
it already exists.
Installing in "C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest-5" instead.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-win-9477386_latest.zip
"Install Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) (revision: 9.0)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) in C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest-5
"Install Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) (revision: 9.0)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) (revision: 9.0)" finished.
```

So it appears that I'm installing them for the 5th time!  After the installation Android Studio still doesn't seem to see that it's installed.

Any idea why Android Studio doesn't see the Android SDK is intalled?  I'm using Android Studio to test React Native applications.  I'm wondering if this will prevent me from being able to debug React Native Applications.  Is it safe for me to delete C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest through C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest-4?

I see the following in a command prompt:

```
C:\>DIR C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is C2D6-EBDB

 Directory of C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools

03/14/2023  06:05 AM    <DIR>          .
03/13/2023  07:03 AM    <DIR>          ..
02/27/2023  06:59 AM    <DIR>          bin
03/09/2023  04:34 AM    <DIR>          latest
03/09/2023  04:35 AM    <DIR>          latest-2
03/13/2023  10:20 AM    <DIR>          latest-3
03/14/2023  06:04 AM    <DIR>          latest-4
03/14/2023  06:05 AM    <DIR>          latest-5
02/27/2023  06:59 AM    <DIR>          lib
03/09/2023  04:30 AM           109,836 NOTICE.txt
03/09/2023  04:30 AM                84 source.properties
               2 File(s)        109,920 bytes
               9 Dir(s)  623,560,048,640 bytes free

C:\>echo %ANDROID_HOME%
C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

C:\>
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem, reinstalling it repeatedly will generate a new "latest" file, but Android Studio won't recognize it until I delete the `cmdline-tools` folder and then reinstall it. This resolves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for too many days now, and the fix was to download an older (more stable) version of Android Studio. ie: for me right now the lastest one is Giraffe, and the one that worked was Iguana.

I'd like to complain to AndroidStudio about that, I believe they should tell the user and launch both the lastest stable version and the new version as Beta. Sorry, just had to mention that somewhere, still not sure where to contact Android Studio about this.

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio, open the **SDK Manager**.

Navigate to the **SDK Tools tab**.

Check to see **if Android SDK Command-line Tools are enabled**. If not, **check it and apply the changes**.

For some reason, after updating Android Studio, I got this error too. It appears that some new requirement **was not automatically installed** for some reason. **So install it manually**.

This fixed it for me.

Comment: When you say check it, do you mean to put a checkmark beside Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) and then checking Apply?  That's how I've been installing it and at the end it remains unchecked.  That's where I'm seeing the 
`Package "com.android.repository.impl.generated.v2.RemotePackage@f2c9fb88" (cmdline-tools;latest) should be installed in 
"C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest" but 
it already exists.
Installing in "C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest-5" instead.
` message.

Comment: What worked for me was deleting the latest directory with everything in it and simply running the installation again.